# unhandled security exception when flash try to post dato to my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, post, unhandled-exception

I'm building an action that basically handles receiving post data from a flash app, but when the flash make the post (with a long xml string) its seem like mvc frakework block the post and i get the folowing outputs:

Response headers:

POST http://mysite.com/mycontroller 302 Found

GET  http://mysite.com/Error/Generic?aspxerrorpath=/mycontroller 200 OK

Event Viewer:

Event message: An unhandled security exception has occurred.

I have tried :

On my controller  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), ValidateInput(false)]
On my view : ValidateRequest="false"

crossdomain.xml in the root of the application.

low level of trust in .net configuraction.

I have tested locally and works it, but when upload to production server i get :

An unhandled security exception has occurred.

Comment: So, my question is WHY am I getting this security exception? And how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem in the code that generated the exception, it was not the flash. The only problem with de flash and mvc is that any redirect, redirectoaction, o return other view does not work after the flash post.